# Data API Ignoring passed parameters/tags

Tags: youtube-api

We have an application that is making calls out to YouTube by passing a series of tags. It then takes those responses and passes them to various client applications (website, mobile apps) to display a UI with categorized videos. Here is an example (but not actual) request that we are making to YouTube:

> https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/equipment/remstar-se%7Cgel-blue%7Cresistance-control%7Caccessories?author=philipsrespironics&alt=json&v=2&max-results=50

In this instance, it sometimes returns the results as expected, then others it is entirely ignoring some of the tags as well as the author parameter and we receive 1000s of results, not limited by author and seemingly only to some of the tags we pass. It is very random. This was noticed for the first time on Friday AM. Before this, the app was working fine for months.

Is there anything that would cause this on YouTube's end, and if so, how do we resolve?